# Issue with using tables in sql queries

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a syntax issue with the following two queries which I don't know how to fix

I posted them [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bca78/67) and [there](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bca78/76)

```
select model from  
(
select model, price from PC
join Product
on Product.model=PC.model
union all 
select model, price from Laptop
join Product
on Product.model=Laptop.model
union all 
select model, price from Printer
join Product
on Product.model=Printer.model
) XXX
where price = (select max(price) from XXX);

select model from 
(
  select model, price from pc  
  union all
  select model, price from laptop
  union all
  select model price from printer 
) as x
where price=greatest( select max(price) from pc,
                      select max(price) from laptop,
                      select max(price) from printer )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to determine the model that has the largest price? If so, just change your query to sort by price and select one result.

```
select model from  
(
select model, price from PC
join Product
on Product.model=PC.model
union all 
select model, price from Laptop
join Product
on Product.model=Laptop.model
union all 
select model, price from Printer
join Product
on Product.model=Printer.model
) XXX
order by price desc limit 0, 1;
```

You can use the same technique for the second query like so:

```
select model from 
(
  select model, price from pc order by price desc limit 0, 1 
  union all
  select model, price from laptop order by price desc limit 0, 1
  union all
  select model, price from printer order by price desc limit 0, 1
) as x
```